# Creating knowledge graphs in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

1.Can Neo4j store RDF directly? we understand it can import RDF and export RDF but how is the data stored internally.
We also understand in Neo4j we can create property graphs and make it as a KG using APOC procedures and algorithms available,is that the case or are we missing anything?
2. We would like to understand, how an entity will be tagged against an ontology in Neo4j KG implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can import RDF data into Neo4j, however it will not be exactly in that format. Using [Neosemantics](https://neo4j.com/labs/neosemantics/), the triples will be converted into a property graph.

Neosematics can reconvert the property graph data back into triples should that be required.